# How to Reduce 3G data Usage of Google Map API Android

Tags: android, google-maps, 3g

I am developing an application that requires location of a user and display it on a Google Map embedded in my app. My app works pretty well when wifi is connected, while my 3G is not fast enough to support so much data flow with Google Map API so that the map cannot be displayed.

In fact, I only need the map to display on rather than all traffic, satellite and other information Google possibly provides. It seems not possible to store Google Map in phone due to Term of Use and other limitations. Are there any ways to control the data that Google send to me when API is used? Or should I use another map source?

Comment: You could use another map source like osmdroid. I don't know of any way to control the data that google sends to you.

Comment: @Warpzit Thank you very much. I found out that it was my program's problem, I ran too much programs in a single thread. Google map is still quite good in terms of speed.